# MySQL set type on the column

Tags: mysql, set

I was trying to get my column to be in set type on MySQL, but I got an error:

> Syntax error near 'COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' NOT NULL FIRST, COMMENT='' REMOVE PARTITIONING' at line 2

```
ALTER TABLE `Recipe`
CHANGE `Ingredients` `Ingredients` set COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' NOT NULL FIRST,
COMMENT=''
REMOVE PARTITIONING;
```

Please help and appreciated.

Comment: Mind telling *what error* so someone could help? And also the table definition at the moment.

Comment: Syntax error near 'COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' NOT NULL FIRST, COMMENT='' REMOVE PARTITIONING' at line 2

Comment: `SET('value1', 'value2', .. , 'valueN')`

Comment: Syntax error near 'COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '(\'a\',\'b\',\'c\')' FIRST, COMMEN' at line 2 SQL command
ALTER TABLE `Recipe`
CHANGE `Ingredients` `Ingredients` set COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '(\'a\',\'b\',\'c\')' FIRST,
COMMENT=''
REMOVE PARTITIONING;

Comment: You better use a GUI like HeidiSQL to make the changes. It can show you the code, that you need.

Answer (score 0):

`COLLATE` should be after `CHARACTER SET`, which is table level, not column level.

```
ALTER TABLE `Recipe`
CHANGE `Ingredients` `Ingredients` INT NOT NULL FIRST,
COMMENT=''
CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'
REMOVE PARTITIONING;
```

***SQLFidele demo: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2f62a***